# how to take the count from sequential values

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to print sequentially from 20190930 to 20201006. Below loop will help do that. Now, I want to store the number of lines printed into a variable?

```
start=20190930
end=$(date -d"2 days ago" +"%Y%m%d")

while [[ $start -le $end ]]
do
        echo $start
        start=$(date -d"$start + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d")
done
```

current output:

```
20190930
20191001
20191002
20191003
20191004
20191005
etc etc...
```

If I get the range printed from 20190930 to 20191010 then my output count should be as below:

```
10
```

Comment: Change last line to `done | wc -w` maybe?

Comment: What exactly means "the word count"? The number of lines printed? Or do you consider year, month, day as separate words? Please [edit] your question to clarify this. An example of the current output and the expected output for a case resulting in a few lines only might help to understand your requirement. ... If you want to count the lines instead of or in addition to the current output, you can increment a counter variable.

Comment: @Bodo i have edited my question now. This may help understand the problem statement  better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this solution (not tested):

```
start=20190930
end=$(date -d"2 days ago" +"%Y%m%d")
i=0

while [[ $start -le $end ]]
do
        i=$((i+1))
        echo $start
        start=$(date -d"$start + 1 day" +"%Y%m%d")
done

echo "output count : $i"
```

Comment: Thanks! But this didn't give me the total count.

Comment: ? No? What then?

Comment: instead of total count i would get something as:
output count : i+1

Comment: i used instead as i=$((i+1)) and got the desired results